# OpenStack Nova floating_ips on nova client doesn't exist

Tags: python, api, openstack

A call to a setup and functional nova client using nova version "2" has no floating_ips attribute.

```
from novaclient import client as NovaClient
class FloatingIpProvisioner():
    def __init__(self, os_session):
        self.nova = NovaClient.Client(version="2", session=os_session)

    def AddFloatingIpToInstance(self, instance):
        self.nova.floating_ip_pools
        floating_ip = self.nova.floating_ips.create()
        instance = self.nova.servers.find(name="test")
        instance.add_floating_ip(floating_ip)
        return floating_ip

instance = NovaClient.Client(version="2", session=session).servers.find(name="ansiblemaster")
floatingIp = FloatingIpProvisioner(session).AddFloatingIpToInstance(instance)
```

When calling above file we have Error:

```
File "provision.py", line 68, in AddFloatingIpToInstance
    floating_ip = self.nova.floating_ips.create()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'floating_ips'
```

This is the way Openstack and many 3rd party tutorials add floating ips to instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'floating_ips'

Most modern OpenStack deployments no longer use the legacy Nova network implementation, and instead use [Neutron](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Neutron) to manage networks and addresses. This means the Nova server does not provide the necessary API endpoints, so the `floating_ips` resource and methods are no longer available.

You would need to interact with Neutron in order to create a new floating ip address.

If you are writing your own OpenStack client you may want to investigate the [shade](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shade) module.  This wraps around many of the OpenStack APIs to provide a more convenient programming interface.  For example, your code becomes:

```
import shade

cloud = shade.openstack_cloud()    

def AddFloatingIpToInstance(self, server_name, external_network='public'):
    server = cloud.get_server(server_name)
    ip = cloud.create_floating_ip(external_network)
    cloud.add_ips_to_server(server, ips=[ip])
```